# Redis ZADD: update only when score is lower

Tags: redis

I need to store the lowest score for each key I add to the set, but when I do `ZADD`, Redis overwrites the score with the new value even if the score is higher.

```
ZADD myorderset 1 'one' 2 'two' 3 'three'
(integer) 3

ZRANGE myorderset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "one"
2) "1"
3) "two"
4) "2"
5) "three"
6) "3"

ZADD myorderset 5 'three'
(integer) 0

ZRANGE myorderset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "one"
2) "1"
3) "two"
4) "2"
5) "three"
6) "5"
```

In the example case, I need the key 'three' not be updated since the new score is higher (5) than the existing (3). Is there a way to do this natively or do I need to create a script in Lua?

I've been researching `ZADD` modifiers *`(XX, NX, CH)`* but none of them do what I need.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried eval lua script?

Comment: @Gawain Yes, I have a script in Lua that does the checking and only updates if the score is lower, but I wanted to know if there is a possibility to do it natively, I have not found any command to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lua script for this CAS use case would be the simplest and idiomatic solution:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD myorderset 1 'one' 2 'two' 3 'three'
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "local s = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[2]) if not s or s > ARGV[1] then redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2]) end" 1 myorderset 5 'three'
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myorderset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "one"
2) "1"
3) "two"
4) "2"
5) "three"
6) "3"
127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "local s = redis.call('ZSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[2]) if not s or s > ARGV[1] then redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2]) end" 1 myorderset 2 'three'
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE myorderset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "one"
2) "1"
3) "three"
4) "2"
5) "two"
6) "2"
```

Comment: Thanks, finally I use a Lua script.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single command or command option to do it both. You can either use combination of `ZSCORE` with `ZADD`(in lua). Alternatively("It is/looks like over-engineered") you may use `ZUNIONSTORE` with the `aggregate` option `MIN`.

> With the `AGGREGATE` option, it is possible to specify how the results of the union are aggregated. This option defaults to SUM, where the score of an element is summed across the inputs where it exists. When this option is set to either `MIN` or `MAX`, the resulting set will contain the minimum or maximum score of an element across the inputs where it exists.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD base 1 a 2 b 5 c
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD new 3 c
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZUNIONSTORE base 2 base new AGGREGATE MIN
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> DEL new
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE base 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "a"
2) "1"
3) "b"
4) "2"
5) "c"
6) "3"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD new 5 b
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZUNIONSTORE base 2 base new AGGREGATE MIN
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> DEL new
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE base 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "a"
2) "1"
3) "b"
4) "2"
5) "c"
6) "3"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

If you prefer,

- You may generate `new` set name with random string in application level
- Put `EXPIRE` to this new set, no need to `DEL` the new key manually after the `ZUNIONSTORE`, it will be expired eventually.
- It can be done in `MULTI`/`EXEC` in a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks, finally I use a Lua script.